# For Bubble Sort in Ruby, why does one implementation work, and the other returns a

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to complete a bubble_sort method in Ruby, but for some reason, this implementation below returns an error.  I can get it to work using the spaceship operator, but I am curious why it returns an error of:

bubblesort.rb:4:in `>': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    arr.length.times do
        arr.each_with_index do |num, i|
            arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i] if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
        end
    end
    puts "#{arr}"
end

arr = [1,5,4,8,2,4,6]

bubble_sort(arr)
```

Thanks lurker!  This worked:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    arr.length.times do
        arr.each_with_index do |num, i|
            if i < arr.size - 1 && arr[i] > arr[i+1]
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
            end
        end
    end
    puts "#{arr}"
end
```

Comment: Well the `arr[i+1]` goes out of bounds when you hit the highest index for `i`. You need to fix that. :)

Comment: just did that, yep, sorry about that.  I just edited, thanks for the help!